# Как получить DOM(html) страницы для парсера на JQuery?

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery

Есть парсер html страницы сайта погоды на jquery (сокращённый вариант):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
let town = $('div').eq(27).children('h1').text();
let temper = $('div').eq(30).children('span').text();});
```

Как получить по url запросу DOM(html) страницы и скормить его данному примеру парсера? При этом, необходимо получать данные на русском языке (сайт изначально на английском *'foreca.com'*) и относительно места нахождения (город и данные о погоде).
Скрипт запускается на смартфоне ***не в node.js***, с возможностью подключения следующих библиотек:

- JQuery;
- JQery UI;
- Chrome Frame;
- Dojo;
- Ext Core;
- Moo Tools;
- Prototype;
- script.aculo.us;
- SWFObject;
- WebFont Loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в ошибке https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS,
для решения которой, необходимо запускать локальный сервер https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server.